# In Java, why does class.getResource("/path/to/res"); not work in the runnable jar when copying files to the system?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, inputstream

I have been working on a project that requires the user to "install" the program upon running it the first time. This installation needs to copy all the resources from my "res" folder to a dedicated directory on the user's hard drive. I have the following chunk of code that was working perfectly fine, but when I export the runnable jar from eclipse, I received a stack trace which indicated that the InputStream was null. The install loop passes the path of each file in the array list to the export function, which is where the issue is (with the InputStream). The paths are being passed correctly in both Eclipse and the runnable jar, so I doubt that is the issue. I have done my research and found other questions like this, but none of the suggested fixes (using a classloader, etc) have worked. I don't understand why the method I have now works in Eclipse but not in the jar?

(There also exists an ArrayList of File called installFiles)

```
private static String installFilesLocationOnDisk=System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Documents/[project name]/Resources/";

public static boolean tryInstall(){
    for(File file:installFiles){
//for each file, make the required directories for its extraction location
        new File(file.getParent()).mkdirs();
        try {
//export the file from the jar to the system 
            exportResource("/"+file.getPath().substring(installFilesLocationOnDisk.length()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static void exportResource(String resourceName) throws Exception {
    InputStream resourcesInputStream = null;
    OutputStream resourcesOutputStream = null;
    //the output location for exported files
    String outputLocation = new File(installFilesLocationOnDisk).getPath().replace('\\', '/');
    try {
        //This is where the issue arises when the jar is exported and ran.
        resourcesInputStream = InstallFiles.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
        if(resourcesInputStream == null){
                throw new Exception("Cannot get resource \"" + resourceName + "\" from Jar file.");
        }
        //Write the data from jar's resource to system file
        int readBytes;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        resourcesOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputLocation + resourceName);
        while ((readBytes = resourcesInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            resourcesOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        //Close streams
        resourcesInputStream.close();
        resourcesOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: Cannot get resource "/textures\gameIcon.png" from Jar file.
```

All help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate, document your code, include the error and format your post so the question is more clear. The easier your question is to understand, the easier it is to solve the problem!

Comment: Eclipse is not a way to produce a production-quality package. Get ant, or gradle, or Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> java.lang.Exception: Cannot get resource "/textures\gameIcon.png" from Jar file.
> ```

The name if the resource is wrong. As the Javadoc of `ClassLoader.getResource(String)` describes (and `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` refers to `ClassLoader` for details):

> The name of a resource is a `/`-separated path name that identifies
>   the resource.

No matter whether you get your resources from the File system or from a Jar File, you should always use `/` as the separator.

Using `\` may sometimes work, and sometimes not: there's no guarantee. But it's always an error.

In your case, the solution is a change in the way that you invoke `exportResource`:

```
String path = file.getPath().substring(installFilesLocationOnDisk.length());
exportResource("/" + path.replace(File.pathSeparatorChar, '/'));
```

Comment: I have made sure that all cases of a slash in my project are / but the stack trace always prints out the path as though it changed the second slash back to a \? For instance, I put in: `/textures/gameIcon.png` but the stack trace says it can not find `/textures\gameicon.png`

Comment: @DaveOverZero How did you make sure of that? `file.getPath()` will return something with backslashes in it, on Windows. In the code in your question you are not replacing the `\ ` with `/`. And if you get this error message, then there must be something wrong in the way in which you replace the backslash with the slash.

Comment: Edit: I found a fix using your suggestion: I changed
`String path = file.getPath().substring(installFilesLocationOnDisk.length());
exportResource("/" + path.replace(File.pathSeparatorChar, '/'));`

to

`String path = file.getPath().substring(installFilesLocationOnDisk.length());
    exportResource("/" + path.replace('\\', '/'));`

essentially I changed File.pathSeparatorChar to \\ since it couldn't find anything for File.pathSeparatorChar

Answer (score 0):

Rename your JAR file to ZIP, uncompress it and check where did resources go.

There is a possibility you're using Maven with Eclipse, and this means exporting Runnable JAR using Eclipse's functionality won't place resources in JAR properly (they'll end up under folder resources inside the JAR if you're using default Maven folder names conventions).

If that is the case, you should use Maven's Assembly Plugin (or a Shade plugin for "uber-JAR") to create your runnable JAR.

Even if you're not using Maven, you should check if the resources are placed correctly in the resulting JAR.

P.S. Also don't do this:

```
.getPath().replace('\\', '/');
```

And never rely on particular separator character - use `java.io.File.separator` to determine system's file separator character.